# Rename standard Homepage Component?

Tags: visualforce, sidebar

I have a requirement to change the name of the standard Sidebar Search - instead of "Search" I want it to say "XYZ", as an example.  I haven't been able to find anywhere that I can change its label.

I'm thinking that I will have to make a new component and do a creative workaround.  Can anybody help with this?